# How to change one-time binding data in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller, one-time-binding

I have a div which show details like **mobilenumber, name etc.** like `{{::mobilenumber}}, {{::name}}`

In that div, there is a button that renders the same values in the new form

By using the button in the form, the user can change the values  but in the div where I am showing details, values don't change after clicking on the button

```
<form ng-submit="form.$valid && saveDetails()">
  <input type="text" class="form-control capitalize" placeholder="Full Name" name="fullname"ng-model="address.fullname" maxlength="50"  ng-trim="true" autocomplete="off" required >
  <span><!-- Mobile Number required --></span>

  <input type="text" class="form-control capitalize" placeholder="Mobile Number" name="mobilenumber" id="mobilenumber"                        ng-model="address.mobilenumber" ng-minlength="10" maxlength="12"  ng-trim="true" autocomplete="off" required>
  <span><!-- Mobile Number required --></span>

  <button ng-click="form.submitted=true><span>Update User Details</span</button>
</form>
```

Do I want to use one-way binding only?

I tried using `$scope.$broadcast('$$rebind:refresh');` but still values don't change.

Any help or guidance would be very helpful for me.

Comment: show your html, please

Comment: The values don't change because you use one time binding (`::mobilenumber`), so it won't update to any new data. It seems you want to update it, so why do you use one time binding?

Comment: @Maximus I already wrote

Comment: Actually I want to show only my update data in the div when user update the form only otherwise it should not update before the button click that update the form

Comment: @VIKASKOHLI, I don't see you html in you question

Comment: Why do you use one-time binding if you don't want one-time binding?

Comment: @Maximus the div tag I already shared.

Comment: @Maximus Now I also shared my form tag in my question. Please see the updated question

Comment: _In that div, there is button that renders the same values in the new form_ - where is this div?

Comment: @Maximus I added this button

Comment: @VIKASKOHLI, let's talk in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132302/discussion-between-maximus-and-vikas-kohli).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to keep some sort of one-way-binding...

What you could do, is just use two way binding but with a dataset in between. It gives some overhead but it is a possible solution to your problem. In order to update the view, you just update the copied data. You can control when the data in the view is updated.

Answer (score 0):

When you use interpolation `{{mobilenumber}}` in your html, angular creates a watcher that watches the property `mobilenumber` on a scope:

```
$scope.$watch('mobilenumber', function() {
   // update DOM
});
```

Whenever the value changes, DOM is updated.

However, if you use one time binding `{{:mobilenumber}}`, as soon as your callback receives truthy value, angular removes the watcher:

```
var unwatch = $scope.$watch('mobilenumber', function() {
   if (value) {
     // update DOM
     unwatch();
   }
);
```

And since there is no more watcher for `mobilenumber`, whenever you update values on the scope inside your `saveDetails()` method, the callback is not triggered and DOM is not updated.

**If you're planning on updating values constantly, you should not use one time binding**. Use regular bindings:

```
<div>{{mobilenumber}}</div>
```

Comment: Actually I want to show only my update data in the div when user update the form only otherwise it should not update before the button click that update the form. So is there any other way to do that ?

Comment: @VIKASKOHLI, please see my updated answer you can [join the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132302/discussion-between-maximus-and-vikas-kohli) if there is anything unclear